# Can i make all the functions in my smart contract as constant?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, remix

What if i make a smart contract that does modify the state, but the all its functions are constant.(it will still compile) It means that i can use my smart contract for free without paying for the gas. Wouldn't this be a lose to the miners?
How does Ethereum handles this situation?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Calling constant function doesn't create transaction. Your client just computes result locally.

However, constant functions can not change state (because they're constant)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change contract state without a blockchain transaction.

The reason it still compiles is because the Solidity compiler does not yet figure out with 100% accuracy which functions modify contract state. When I try to compile it, I do get this compiler warning:

> Warning: Function declared as view, but this expression (potentially) modifies the state (...)

Answer (score 0):

Well, If you can write such kind of code and deploy it ... Yes, it will work, but, the use case for such a contract that can only return static data form any source will be extremely limited.

And as far as I know, suppose you create such a contract, it cannot return anything(dynamic data related to something) as it has nothing inside the contract(say, mapping or arrays or structs).

here is an example:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.7.0;

contract sample {
 address user;
 
 constructor () public{
     user = msg.sender;
 }
 
 function returnUser() public view returns(address){
     return user;
 }
 
 
}
```

Think about it... range of use case of such codes?